# Javascript - What is alternative to find function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, find, cross-browser

I am using `find () function`  for one of my project. Official document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find says that Internet Explorer is not supported. What else can I use?

Comment: Why not polyfill it?

Comment: Meaning? Never heard of that. How?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming) - adding support for browsers that don't support a feature by implementing it just for them. There is a standard implementation for all array methods and similar that don't rely heavily on ES6+ features.

Comment: Okay, but is this good practice? Just for IE we write more code. Shouldnt we use something alternative which works on all browser?

Comment: It's pretty standard to polyfill missing methods. Otherwise you would never actually get to use them - `find()` is older than ES6 and yet if we were working with alternatives, we wouldn't use it because of IE. It also keeps your code consistent - otherwise you have to keep poaching different alternatives for different missing features from different places. Making a patchwork of who-knows-how working features just because of IE. Even the MDN article you linked to includes a link to a polyfill - it's the first under "See Also".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polyfill is a code that provides the functionality that you normally expect the browser to provide you natively. Here is the polyfill for Array.find

```js
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I use this? Do I use function name?

Comment: This code binds the necessary function to Array.find. So, first run this code then you can call it like array.find(element => element > 10)